# How to calculate the squared inverse of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to calculate:

```
gamma=(I-K*A^-1)*OLS;
```

where `I` is the identity matrix, `K` and `A` are diagonal matrices of the same size, and `OLS` is the ordinary least squares estimate of the parameters.

I do this in Matlab using:

```
gamma=(I-A\K)*OLS;
```

However I then have to calculate:

```
gamma2=(I-K^2*A-2)*OLS;
```

I calculate this in Matlab using:

```
gamma2=(I+A\K)*(I-A\K)*OLS;
```

Is this correct?

Also I just want to calculate the variance of the `OLS` parameters:

The formula is simple enough:

```
Var(B)=sigma^2*(Delta)^-1;
```

Where `sigma` is a constant and `Delta` is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues.

I tried doing this by:

```
Var_B=Delta\sigma^2;
```

But it comes back saying matrix dimensions must agree?

Please can you tell me how to calculate `Var(B)` in Matlab, as well as confirming whether or not my other calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, matrix multiplication does not commute, which makes `A^2 - B^2` not equal to `(A+B)*(A-B)`. However your case is special, because you have an identity matrix in the equation. So your method for finding `gamma2` is valid.

'Var_B=Delta\sigma^2' is not a valid `mldivide` expression. See the documentation. Try  `Var_B=sigma^2*inv(Delta)`. The function `inv` returns a matrix inverse. Although this function can also be applied in your expression to find `gamma` or `gamma2`, the use of the operator `\` is more recommended for better accuracy and faster computation.